# Use build-arg from docker to create json file

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a docker build command which I'm running in Jenkins execute shell

```sh
docker build -f ./fastlane.dockerfile \
  -t fastlane-test \
  --build-arg PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS=$(cat PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS) \
  .
```

`PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS` is a JSON file saved in Jenkins using managed files. And, then, inside my *Dockerfile*, I have

```sh
ARG PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS
ENV PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS=$PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS
WORKDIR /app/packages/web/android/fastlane/PlayStoreCredentials
RUN touch play-store-credentials.json
RUN echo $PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS >> ./play-store-credentials.json
RUN cat play-store-credentials.json
```

`cat` logs out a empty line or nothing at all.

Content of `PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS`:

```
{
  "type": "...",
  "project_id": "...",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "...",
  "client_email": "...",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "...",
  "token_uri": "...",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "...",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "..."
}
```

Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Possibly `PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS="$(cat PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS)"` so your cat is space safe.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Still the same issue. RUN cat play-store-credentials.json logs empty line in jenkins

Comment: Would be helpful if you give an anonymised version of the content of `PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Added it to the question. Nothing special from my point of view in the json file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there *actually* a file named `PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS`? If it is, and if it's a standard JSON file, I would expect your given command line to fail; if the file contains *any* whitespace (which is typical for  JSON files), that command should result in an error like...

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

For example, if I have in `PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS` the sample content from your question, we see:

```
$ docker build -t fastlane-test --build-arg PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS=$(cat PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS) .
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

...because you are not properly quoting your arguments.  If you adopt @β.εηοιτ.βε's suggestion and quote the `cat` command, it appears to build as expected:

```
$ docker build -t fastlane-test --build-arg PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS="$(cat PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS)" .

[...]

Step 7/7 : RUN cat play-store-credentials.json
 ---> Running in 29f95ee4da19
{ "type": "...", "project_id": "...", "private_key_id": "...", "private_key": "...", "client_email": "...", "client_id": "...", "auth_uri": "...", "token_uri": "...", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "...", "client_x509_cert_url": "..." }
Removing intermediate container 29f95ee4da19
 ---> b0fb95a9d894
Successfully built b0fb95a9d894
Successfully tagged fastlane-test:latest
```

You'll note that the resulting file does not preserve line endings; that's because you're not quoting the variable `$PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS` in your `echo` statement. You should write that as:

```
RUN echo "$PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS" >> ./play-store-credentials.json
```

Lastly, it's not clear why you're transferring this data using environment variables, rather than just using the `COPY` command:

```
COPY PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS ./play-store-credentials.json
```

---

In the above examples, I'm testing things using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest

ARG PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS
ENV PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS=$PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS
WORKDIR /app/packages/web/android/fastlane/PlayStoreCredentials
RUN touch play-store-credentials.json
RUN echo $PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS >> ./play-store-credentials.json
RUN cat play-store-credentials.json
```

---

**Update**

Here's an example using the `COPY` command, where the value of the `PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS` build argument is a filename:

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest

ARG PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS
WORKDIR /app/packages/web/android/fastlane/PlayStoreCredentials
COPY ${PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS} play-store-credentials.json
RUN cat play-store-credentials.json
```

If I have credentials in a file named `creds.json`, this builds successfully like this:

```
docker build -t fastlane-test --build-arg PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS=creds.json .
```

Comment: Looking at this in your answer, `touch play-store-credentials.json && echo $PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS >> ./play-store-credentials.json` seems an overkill (unless OP is doing something in the middle of this). So, replacing those two runs with a single `RUN echo "${PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS}" > play-store-credentials.json` seems a bit more natural.

Comment: I tried using copy but what I get after changing ```PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS="$(cat PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS)"PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS```  to ```PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS=$PLAY_STORE_CREDENTIALS``` is ```COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat var/jenkins_home/workspace/Android-Build-Test@tmp/config3168235257682048127tmp: file does not exist
```

Comment: But to be clear I can access other files with the same commands just not this one JSON file I also do the same proces for .env file and it works

Comment: I've included an example of using the `COPY` command to install the credentials in the image.